# I accidentally deleted my images on minio server. Is it possible to restore minio backup (with and without docker)?

Tags: javascript, docker, dockerfile, minio

I have a minio server running. I accidentally deleted my images on minio server. But I have the backup of images in my local in a zip file. How do I restore it? I am using docker. should I mount or something?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a zip file of the docker images, send the zip to your server, unzip it and load the image using this command:

```
docker load -i backupimage.img
```

Comment: I have the backup files of the minio data(media files). not docker image backup file.